# News script inserting news data, but not editing news

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I've got this code working so it can insert news into it's table, but the problem is the editing news afterwards if need be.

I've been trying different ways, but it seems to not be working full stop.

```
<? 
if(!$id)
echo("Please choose a page to edit..");
elseif($id==edit)
{
$select = mysql_query("select * from news where newsid = '$id'");
$article = mysql_fetch_array($select);
?>
<form action="edit-news.php?id=edited" method="post">
    Title:<br />
    <input name="readuser" type="text" value="<? echo("$article[title]");?>" size="70" />
Article Content:<br />
<textarea name="pageuser" cols="40" rows="6"><? echo("$article[text1]");?></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Update article" />
</form>
<?
}
elseif($page==edited)
{
$text1 = $_POST[pageuser];
$title = $_POST[readuser];
$updateit = mysql_query("update news set text1 = '$text1' AND title = '$title' where newsid = $id");
echo("Article updated");
}
?>
```

I get no error messages when visiting the page anymore (thankfully!!!) but it's just not editing the articles.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: While formatting, I've seen the comment `}//end of if($submit).` This doesn't fit the provided code. The closing `}` belongs to either `while` or `elseif`. You also have multiple `?>`. Please provide the complete code.

Comment: New code reposted. Please pick at it :) That doesn't do the trick either :( I'm hopeless.. I want it to edit the article when viewing "edit-news.php?id=11"

Answer (score 3):

Assign a value to your text inputs and textareas so that they will display the article for editing:

```
<input name="title" size="40" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?>">

<textarea name="text1"  rows="7" cols="30"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text1); ?></textarea>

<textarea name="text2" rows="7" cols="30"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($text2); ?></textarea>
```

Also change `<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>` to:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>
```

---

Side note: `mysql_*` is deprecated, use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements. Your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection. A quick fix would be:

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsid='" . (int)$_GET['newsid'] . "'",$connect);
```

Also `mysql_real_escape_string()` is better than `mysql_escape_string()` because the latter doesn't respect the character set. Neither are better than a prepared statement though.

Comment: New code reposted. Please pick at it :) That doesn't do the trick either :( I'm hopeless.. I want it to edit the article when viewing "edit-news.php?id=11"

Comment: Ironically `that doesn't help` doesn't help me to help you solve the problem. What does it do exactly, does it get the data in the query and just not pass it to the form, does it display OK but doesn't update??

Comment: It just doesn't display the data from news table when you go to edit-news.php?id=11

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE news SET title = '$title', dtime = NOW(), text1 = '$text1', text2 = '$text2' WHERE newsid = '$newsid'
```

Comment: New code reposted. Please pick at it :) That doesn't do the trick either :( I'm hopeless.. I want it to edit the article when viewing "edit-news.php?id=11"

Comment: What is `elseif($id==edit)` ?   If you want id to be a numeric value representing id of the news (`edit-news.php?id=11`) then in your form you have to make the action attribute to send data to the same page `edit-news.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>` Otherwise ID is lost. If suddenly id becomes "edit" or "edited", than in your Ifs statement you need `if($id == "edit")` and `elseif($id == "edited")`  (I assume you have `$id = $_GET["id"]` somewhere up the page?